# How to determine a Hilbert class field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I tried to solve the exercise VIII.XX in [**Number Fields** by *Marcus*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387902791). It asks to find the Hilbert class field of $Q(\sqrt m)$ for $m=-6,-10,-21,-30$. And the emphasis of this question is on the first two.

**Attempt to solve the first case.**
I knew that the class number of $K=Q(\sqrt{-6})$ is $2$, so its Hilbert class field extension $H/K$ is of degree $2$. Since all groups of order $4$ are abelian, we know that $H$ is also abelian over $Q$. Further, by the computation of the conductor, we know that $H\subset Q(\zeta_{24})$, where $\zeta_{24}$ is a $24$-th primitive root of unity. After we compute explicitly the galois group of $Q(\zeta_{24})/Q$ is isomorphic with h$C_2\times C_2\times C_2$. Noting that $\sqrt{-6}=(\zeta_8+\zeta_8^7)(1+2\zeta_3)$, we deduce that the galois group of $Q(\zeta_{24})/K$ is isomorphic with $G=C_2\times C_2$. So there are $3$ subgroups of $G$ of index $2$. And I cannot decide which one of them is the subgroup fixing $H$. Of course, if we write out all fixed fields of the three subgroups, then, by examining the decomposition of ideals, we can determine, or conclude, that $H=Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt{-3})$. But I think there must be a way of deciding this without this trial and error.
In fact, in the second case, $K=Q(\sqrt{-10})$, there are $7$ possibilities of $H$! After some calculations moreover, I found that $H=Q(\sqrt{-10},\sqrt5)$. But my method is again trial and error. And I want to find a way to determine $H$ without such brute force.

> **Question**
>   Given a specific field $K/Q$, what is the standard, or the most efficient, way in determining its Hilber class field $H$?

I looked into [**Algebraic Number Fields** by *Janusz*](http://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Algebraic_number_fields.html?id=RT5R_29X69wC&redir_esc=y), but the example I found there is the case $Q(\sqrt{-5})$, in which the galois group of $Q(\zeta_{20})/K$ is cyclic of order $4$, thus having a unique subgroup of index $2$, and so cannot help me here.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is helpful, but for $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$ case....

You know that $H/E$ is quadratic, and thus $H = E(\sqrt{D})$ for some $D \in E$. $H/E$ is an unramified extension, however all number fields are ramified over $\mathbb{Q}$, so clearly $D$ must factor into ramified primes of $E$.

I looked over $2$ first. I don't remember why, but I convinced myself at one time that for a quadratic extension to be unramified, you need to find a $D$ whose prime factorization is square. (hopefully this is fresh in your mind so you'll be able to work out why!) So I observe

$$(2, \sqrt{-6})^2 = (2)$$

However, $2$ is clearly (?) not a square. Thus $E(\sqrt{2})$ is an unramified extension.

---

I also vaguely recall a general theorem that the Hilbert class field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ consists of adjoining square roots of the prime factors of $m$, with appropriate signs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The general theorem at the end is quite helpful.Also, I need to ponder more upon the entire process, to make sure that it applies to other cases as well. Thanks again. :D

Comment: BTW, is there a reference for the general theorem in the end of the answer? Thanks again.

Comment: I am a bit surprised by the last paragraph. Look at [this quadratic field](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/84131/11619) for example. Its class group has order five. So therefore its Hilbert class field should be its quintic extension. But by adjoining square roots you only get extensions of degrees of a power of two?

Comment: @Jyrki: Hrm. Now this is bothering me. Which is annoying because I don't *like* class field theory, but I'm going to have to look things up anyways if I want to stop being annoyed! Maybe I'm remembering something about real quadratic extensions, or maybe just something about two-torsion.

Comment: Very sorry to do that to you. I would help, if I could. But my own understanding of class field theory is rather superficial.

Comment: Dear Hurkyl, What you are remembering is the characterization of the *genus field* of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$, namely the maximal subextension of $H$ which is abelian over $\mathbb Q$.  It corresponds to the maximal elemenatry $2$-abelian quotient of the class group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{m})$.  Regards,