# Class group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-55})$ and finding representatives for ideal classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

My first step in computing the class group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-55})$ was to compute the Minkowski bound. Initially, I said $\lambda(-55)=2\sqrt{-55}/\pi<2(8)/3<6$ and I went the normal way of finding an ideal of norm 5, $(5, \sqrt{-55})$ and this has a contribution to the class group since it is non-principal. But then I realised that I could get a better bound on $\lambda(-55)=2\sqrt{-55}/\pi<2(7.5)/3=5$. So in fact, I should have got no contribution from the ideal $(5, \sqrt{-55})$ and should have got that this ideal is in the same class as an ideal of norm $<5$.

> I don't see how to get an ideal of norm $<5$ from $(5, \sqrt{-55})$ and I'm not sure why my argument above was wrong.

In more complicated situations, I'm worried that by making a mistake similar to the above, I would get much larger class groups than is correct. How do I avoid this mistake.

> Is there a way of spotting if an ideal is in the same ideal class as an integral ideal of smaller norm, in general?

Comment: for imaginary quadratic fields use the method of quadratic forms - it gives all you need

Comment: @user8268 I don't know what quadratic forms are. I just looked up a definition on Wikipedia, but I don't see how they're helpful.

Comment: @user8268 and James http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to note is that ideal classes are different from ideals, we say $I$ is in the class of  $J$ if $\exists (a),(b)$ with $(a)I=(b)J$. With this in mind, consider $(4\sqrt{-55})(5,\sqrt{-55})=(20\sqrt{-55},-220)=(\sqrt{-55})$. Now consider the ideal $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-55}}{2})$. I claim this is in the same class as $(5,\sqrt{-55})$.

Indeed, consider $$(10\sqrt{-55})(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-55}}{2})=(20\sqrt{-55},5\sqrt{-55}+275)=(\sqrt{-55})$$

This answers your original question.

To get an ideal of norm $<5$, you want to consider ideals with norm $2$ or $3$. The way we do this is to determine whether $(2) , (3)$ are ramified in $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-55})$.

Since $-55\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ we know that Disc($K)=-55$, and since neither $2$ nor $3$ divides 55, we see that neither prime is ramified. Thus, it remains to decide whether they are split completely or inert.

$(3)$ remains a prime in $K$, since $3$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $-55$, so we can discount ideals of norm $3$.

$(2)\equiv1\pmod{8}$, so we know $(2)$ splits completely in $K$. The ideal  I=$(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-55}}{2})$ is a prime ideal of norm $2$, since $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-55}}{2})(2,\frac{1-\sqrt{-55}}{2})=(2)$. A computation shows that $I^2$ is not principal, and indeed, that $I^2\neq \bar I$. Hence, $I$ is not of order $3$. We compute either $I^3$, to give us $\bar I $, or $(I^2)^2$, to give us a principal ideal. Either way, we see that $I$ has order 4, and the class group is henceforth $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: How do you get $(20\sqrt{-55},-220)=(\sqrt{-55})$?

Comment: I've made a mistake in my answer actually, it should be $(4\sqrt{-55})$. However, for an arbitrary ring, $R$, consider the ideal generated by $(f,g)$, where $f$ and $g$ are NOT coprime in $R$. What can this also be written as?

Comment: In fact I think the first bit of my answer is slightly sketchy as a whole. However, you don't actually need to explicitly find the ideal that is in the class of $(5,\sqrt{-55})$ to compute the class group

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I'm not sure really. If $d$ is a common divisor of $f, \, g$ then $(f,g)\subseteq (d)$ but I'm not sure what $(f,g)$ equals unless I somehow know that this is principal.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: since $(3\pm\sqrt{-55})/2$ has norm $2^4$, the smallest power of $2$ that can occur as a norm of an imaginary element in the ring, we have $(2)=P^n(\overline{P})^{4-n}$ for $n\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$; but if both exponents were greater than zero then $2$ would have a proper divisor in the ring which is false. So $(2)=P^4$ or $(2)=(\overline{P})^4$, and either way a four-cycle $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{4Z}$ is generated. Since no other ideal below the Minkowski bound is available, this four-cycle is the entire class group.

How would ideals with norm $5$ fit into this class group? First off, $(5,\sqrt{-55})$ is actually not prime in this ring. It would be so if the ring consisted only of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-55}]$ integers, but that is false when the radicand in a quadratic field is $\equiv1\bmod4$. The actual prime ideals of norm $5$ take the form

$Q_k=(5,\frac12(5+k\sqrt{-55})),$

where $k$ is an odd integer not divisible by $5$. $Q_k$ is identical with $Q_{-k}$ and $Q_{10\pm k}$, so only $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ are actually distinct. We then find that

$Q_1^2=Q_3^2=(5,\sqrt{-55})$

$Q_1^3=Q_3, Q_3^3=Q_1$ (cubing the ideal multiplies $k$ by $3$, but then $Q_9$ reduces to $Q_1$ from the equalities given above)

$Q_k^4=(5,\sqrt{-55})^2=(5)$

These relationships give the same four-cycle as we found with the norm-$2$ ideals.

Comment: Yeah, this works. The argument is somewhat similar to the one Alex B use [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84131/11619). It is worth our while to have this example as well. The point of my comment is to link these two threads.  For my own benefit, mostly :-)