# Methods to show that an ideal isn't principal in a quadratic number field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $a,m\in\mathbb Z_{\ge2}$. Let's consider the ring $A=\mathbb Z[(1+\alpha)/2]$, where $\alpha^2=1-4a^m$, and the ideal $I=(a,(1+\alpha)/2)$, we need to show that $I^n$ is non-principal when $0<n<m$.

It's easy to show by induction that $I^n=(a^n,(1+\alpha)/2)$, and we have $A/a^nA\cong\mathbb Z/a^n\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/a^n\mathbb Z$, $A/I^n\cong\mathbb Z/a^n\mathbb Z$. Note that $I^m=((1+\alpha)/2)$, which is principal.

Since the case is a bit more general than computations in specific quadratic fields, maybe there's more general methods to determine whether an ideal is principal.

Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I think that here you are expected to rely on specific properties of imaginary quadratic fields. Most notably the norm. See [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/84131/11619), where the asker is using the norm to exclude the possibility that the ideal could be principal. Not sure that the technique matches your needs exactly, but it sure rang a bell.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks. The norm of $a^n$ or $(1+\alpha)/2$ is a power of $a$, not necessarily a prime or primary, sadly. Additional note: it's a starred exercise in a mid-term examination of algebra mostly at undergraduate level (i.e, that of M.Artin's Algebra, say), and I failed to work it out during the exam.

Comment: The element of minimal norm in $A \setminus Z$ is $(1+\alpha)/2$. So all you need to do is verify that the powers of I are not generated by integers.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Therefore a fortiori $(1+\alpha)/2$ is irreducible, and a principal ideal containing an irreducible element should be an ideal generated by that, or the unity ideal, right? Thanks!